# Maximizing difference of sums

Tags: algorithm, math

> Given a list of N distinct positive integers, partition the list into two 
>   sublists of n/2 size such that the difference between sums of the sublists 
>   is maximized.
>   Assume that n is even and determine the time complexity.

I know, I know, it's a homework question. But the issue is not necessarily in solving it, but in understanding what exactly is being asked. I can safely say that half of the problem is simple to solve, but I don't think I get what is meant by

> such that the difference between sums of the sublists 
>   is maximized.

Any help in illustrating the "plan of attack" on this would be appreciated

Comment: Sort, then split down the middle. For better performance, you don't actually need to sort, just partition. For that, you can use [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), which can be done in `O(N)`

Comment: It wants you to split a list of positive ints into two halves, with all the big numbers in one half and the small numbers in the other.

Comment: That's what I thought it meant. but I just got confused on the wording. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asuume you have this list

- `list : 1 ,1 , 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 1, 2, 20`

it means you can split it to sub lists with size of n/2 in many ways 
such like this

- `sub list 1 : 3, 1, 5, 6, 1`
- `sub list 2 : 1 ,1 , 2, 2, 20`

now calculate sum of each sub list

- `sum of sub list 1 is 16`
- `sum of sub list 2 is 26`
- `diffrence between them is : 10`

but question want two sub lists such has this condition

- **question condition** : difference between sums of the sublists is maximized.

it means between all ways that we can split main list into two sublists choose one way that has the **question condition**.

for example if we split above list into this lists

- `sub list 1 : 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 , 2`
- `sub list 2 : 2, 3, 5 , 6 , 20`
- `sum of sub list 1 is 6`
- `sum of sub list 2 is 36`
- `diffrence between them is : 30`

which is more than last result and also is maximum